# Extract certain Text and URI parts from downloaded html pages

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have downloaded many html pages and I want to extract from each such tags (the single files are stored in directories and subdirectories)

```
            <h2><a href="index.html">TITLE</a></h2>
            <p class="postTime">7 September, 2011 - 20:43</p>

            <p>TEXT</p>
            <p>TEXT</p>

            <p class="postmetadata">
              Posted by Person in <a href="../../category/THECATEGORY/index.html"
```

I need to extract the following

From `h2` : TITLE
From `p` (the one w/o any class): TEXT, TEXT
From `a` within `postmetadata` class : THECATEGORY

Could use any programming language for this, but preferrably Python. I am using Linux.

Comment: Use a XML parser like xmllint.

Comment: Get familiar with [Beautiful Soup](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/BeautifulSoup/3.2.1). It is a great HTML/XML parser and will help you get this done in no time.